# PHP Fatal error: Failed opening required 'goutte'

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04, behat

I am running `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` and my php version is `5.5.9-1+sury.org~precise+1`. I want to test a web page, so included in my project `behat`, `mink` and its `goutte` extension using composer.

When I run `behat` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning: require(goutte): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/andreea/public_html/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112
PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'goutte' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/andreea/public_html/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112
```

My `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "glp/glp",
    "description": "My page",
    "require": {
        "paymill/paymill": "v3.0.0",
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.5.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-extension": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }    
}
```

And `behat.yml` is:

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
    goutte: ~
```

I need some help to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one level of indentation in front of **goutte**:

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      goutte: ~
```